# How to remove duplicate Chrome profile entries in Gnome applications menu?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, shortcuts, appmenu

Ubuntu 18.04 with Google Chrome installed.

I have numerous Chrome profiles, and to make it easy to open specific profiles, I have used Chrome's "create shortcut" feature to add shortcuts to each Chrome profile on my desktop. My desktop looks like this.

I've made changes a few times, deleting the shortcuts from the desktop and recreating or renaming them.

I have attached an image of Chrome shortcuts on my desktop.

[screenshot of Chrome profile shortcuts on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbWIT.png)

I guess that when a new shortcut is created in Chrome, it's automatically added to the Gnome applications menu too. Great. The issue is that for some reason, ONE of the profiles appears to be duplicated in my Gnome applications menu. See the other image I've attached. I have highlighted the entries that were auto-added after creating Chrome shortcuts.

[screenshot of Gnome applications menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DdgS.png)

I can't work out why this is happening. It's only happening with one of the shortcuts, and it happened after the shortcut was deleted from the desktop and then added again from Chrome. However, I did that with all the shortuts and this is the only one being duplicated in the applications menu.

As you can see from the images it's the profile called "email" which is duplicated. This is Chrome profile 2, for some reason I cannot understand.

I have checked under /usr/share/applications and it seems that the profile shortcuts which appear in the menu are not separately listed there (at least nowhere I can easily spot them). There are many .desktop files there which are not shown in the applications menu too.

Can anyone advise on how to get rid of the duplicate entries?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct location. There were a ton of Chrome profile entries under:

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

I deleted all except the batch I created on the last occasion, and that cleared out the duplicates. What I don't understand is why there weren't more duplicates showing, as there were quite a lot for all the profiles. Anyway...